# Create valid words from random letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit of a puzzle - I have created a small game for my kids that is not dissimilar to the likes of Bookworm and Wordsworth. 49 letters are chosen at random from the alphabet (stored in an array), and the kids click adjacent letters to make words. There is a check to match the words to a dictionary file (also in an array), and if the word is valid the chosen letters are replaced in the grid with more random letters. All fine so far.

What I would like to do next is to check the grid to see if there are any valid words left in it, a kind of game over if you like. The problem is that I have no idea where to actually start!

The letters in the grid can be dropped into an array easily enough, but I lack the skills to work out the jQuery or javascript code that can check the grid to for valid words (remembering that the letters have to be adjacent to each other). Letters are displayed in DIV elements as opposed to a table.

So far I have simply managed to lock up the browser in a multitude of loops with the problem only exacerbated because the code needs to run every time a word is correctly found and letters in the grid replaced.

I understand that this is more of a problem solving experiment than a coding question as such, so my apologies if this post breaks any rules here, but does anyone have any idea how best to go about this?

Cheers BS

Comment: if you post the code you have just now it will make it more specific. and maybe its not far off a good solution anyway. (don't forget about http://jsfiddle.net/ too)

Comment: I do not believe that you can do the thing you want to do with anything approaching a reasonable amount of processing power - especially not in anything approaching realtime.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes, I'm starting to think that myself - see my comment further down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting all letters of a row. Then copy the first letter into a string and compare it to the dictionary. Next you take the two first letters and do the same. When you've reached 7 character length you take the 6 last letters and compare it to the dictionary. When you've done all checks in that row, move on to the next row. When all rows are completed do the same for collumns.

psuedo code:

```
for ($currentCollumn=1; $gridWidth > $currentCollumn; $currentCollumn++) {
    $collumn = get collumn as string
    for ($i=1;$i!=7;$i++) {
        get first $i characters of $collumn and compare to dictionary
        }
    for ($i=1;$i!=7;$i++) {
        get last $i characters of $collumn and compare to dictionary
        }
}

for ($currentRow=1; $gridHeight > $currentRow; $currentRow++) {
    $row = get row as string
    for ($i=1;$i!=7;$i++) {
        get first $i characters of $row and compare to dictionary
        }
    for ($i=1;$i!=7;$i++) {
        get last $i characters of $row and compare to dictionary
        }
}
```

---

EDIT: Version 2, since I didn't realize the words weren't limited to straight lines.

start at every possible location.

```
// define variables:
booleanArray path[x][y] = false;  
p = pointerlocation;  
stack[] = p;  
currentString = "";
```

p.up/.down/.left/.right checks path[][] where y+1, y-1, x+1, x-1 respectively. If it's outside the bounds it will return false.

The stack[] works like an x86 stack. Last in, first out.
push() adds a new object onto the stack
pop() gets the last object added to the stack and removes it from the stack

```
function getAllTheStrings(p.x, p.y) {
    while (p) {
        path (p.x, p.y) = true;
        currentString += p.getCharacter();
        // check neighbors
        if (p.up) {
           stack.push(p.up, path, currentString);
        } 
        if (p.down) {
           stack.push(p.down, path, currentString);
        } 
        if (p.left) {
           stack.push(p.left, path, currentString);
        } 
        if (p.right) {
           stack.push(p.right, path, currentString);
        }
        // add current string to list possible words
        foundWords.push(currentString);

        // pop next item from stack
        overwrite variables with stored values of: p, path, currentString

        if (stack is empty) {
        p = false; // end loop
        }
    }
}
```

And that would be called by:

```
function getWords() {
    for ($y=1; $gridHeight > $y; $y++) {
        for ($x=1; $gridWidth > $x; $x++) {
            getAllTheStrings(x,y);
        }
}
```

This function scales very badly with grid size since it has to check every single combination of possible paths. A 1x1 grid would take one test. A 2x2 would take 28 tests. At 3x3 I lost count at about 270 tests.

After the loop is finished `foundWords` would be checked word for word against the whole dictionary. 5 found words and 100 words in the dictionary would give 500 comparisons. In reality the dictionary would have at least a thousand words.

Comment: As far as I understand his problem the letters need to be adjacent not necessarily in a row. Therefore words can also appear in columns.

Comment: The second psuedo code for loop will take care of that unless I missunderstood you. Is it possible for words to be L-shaped on the grid?

Comment: Yes, words can be formed from any shape that can be made by clicking adjacent letters. Thanks for this input, Ill try looking at this in more depth when I get home later. BS

Comment: If that's the case then I would just put a reset-button. The number of possible locations for words are probably high to compute within reasonable time - specially with singlethreaded javascript. I'll give it a try though.

Comment: Hi Filip, I managed to get a loop running that appeared to do the job, but it is sloooww! Far too slow to actually work in practice as it visibly slows the whole thing down.  

I did consider this morning that it might be an idea to create the array of letters for the initial grid and work on it behind the cover of a loading spinner or something, but it would only be valid until letters are replaced, which negates the whole thing again.  

Thanks for your input so far, and if you come up with anything Id like to hear it, but this might be dead in the water so to speak.  
BS

Comment: First off - speedtest it. If it's "within reasonable time" you could start checking just after the grid has been updated in any way. The user would most likely search for words for a while and you could just type something like "are you sure there aren't any words in there?" while the script is still checking in the background. Also, every call to `getAllTheStrings();` could be started in a new thread. Notice that this would stress the cpu a lot while playing.

Comment: Iv been messing about with this at work and it seems to get slower and slower. I'm wondering.. Iv seen a few things about non-ui locking loops, and I'm wondering if I could do this in the background but still allow enough time for the game itself to carry on without interruption? Would this be viable do you think?

Comment: Since javascript isn't multithreaded we'll have to leave time for the ui to update. Every loop is independent from the last one (as long as the stack is preserved) so you could try using javascript timeouts to allow the UI to update. This will however make the script even slower. I think the best available option would be to just add a reset button. You could remove some score on each reset to discourage it.

Comment: Hey Filip, I think you might be right. Iv been playing about tonight and I cant make the loops go fast enough to be of much use - the whole thing just slows down too much. I might well just go for the reset button as you suggested, thanks. One last thing, I'm not too sure of protocol here, so do I mark a post as a correct answer or not? In any case, thanks for your efforts, its much appreciated. All the best - BS

Comment: I'd be glad if you did, or at least give me an upvote :) Cheers!

Comment: I marked the answer as correct - I cant upvote - not enough reputation apparently. Curious that someone has downvoted me for asking the question it seems! Oh well! Many thanks for your help.